# table view not receiving touches when dismissing keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to dismiss keyboard when touching outside of textfield. I have a main view controller view controller and another view controller embedded in the top right corner of the main view. It's embedded using container view (special object in IB).

The problem is that when I add gesture recogniser, the keyboard is dismissed but my another table view (in the center) is not receiving taps (it still scrolling but I can't select row). Table view is also an embedded view controller. This code is in my ViewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And my dissmisKeyboard method:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard 
{
    NSArray *childVc = [self childViewControllers];
    for(id child in childVc)
    {
        if([child isKindOfClass:[MyTableViewController class]])
        {
            [child.tableVIew endEditing:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard 
{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: same result. Keyboard hides, but didSelectRaw: for my table view isn't called